# not correct index with tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing a searching music program.
But I have this problem that print is not my intent so I need help.
I develop with tkinter, requests, lxml, BeautifulSoup
Why this error occurred?

This is my code

```
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.title('TEST')
window.geometry("640x400+100+100")
window.resizable(False, False)

def Search(event):
    listBox.delete(0, 'end')
    count = 1
    query = urlencode(entry.get())

    URL = 'https://music.bugs.co.kr/search/lyrics?q=' + query
    session = requests.Session()
    headers = session.get(URL)
    temp = headers.cookies.get_dict()
    temp['User-Agent'] =     
    res = requests.get(URL, headers=temp)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

    title = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'title'})
    artist = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'artist'})

    for song, singer in zip(title, artist):
        titles = song.get_text()
        artists = singer.get_text()
        listBox.insert(count, "title : " + titles.strip())
        listBox.insert(count, "artist : " + artists.strip())
        count+=1

entry = tkinter.Entry(window)
entry.bind("<Return>", Search)
entry.pack()

listBox = tkinter.Listbox(window, selectmode='extended', height = 0, width=300)
listBox.delete(0)
listBox.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

[Print Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5HOU.png)

Comment: add `count += 1` after the first `listBox.insert()`, otherwise your count index is allways in the middle of the list. (That is why title are all below the middle (added first) and artist above (added second), except for the first one.) You will notice, when you use different songs, with different titles and artists. (That all is a guess)

Comment: Please include the actual error as part of your question.

Comment: `temp['User-Agent'] =   ` points to nothing so that by itself should prevent your code from running. Please also include your imports. I cannot test your code without knowing the imports.